# How to find out how many days have passed since an iOS app was opened the first time by a specific user/device?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cordova, uuid

I created an iOS app and would like to give the users the opportunity to use the app for free for 30 days since the app was installed **and started** the very first time.

After these 30 days I'd like to turn off most functionality. The only way to retain full functionality is to login in with username and password which the user can register for on a dedicated website.

**My problem is:**

When the app was started the very first time, I'd like store a unique identifier and a timestamp of this moment on a remote server. Then I'd know when 30 days have passed for this unique id.

Unfortunately, it seems like the only uuid-like identifier on iOS is [identifierForVendor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device#deviceuuid). According to the docs, when the user removes all apps from the same vendor of the app and then reinstalls them, the uuid changes. Since this uuid would not match the one I stored to the database on my remote server, the user would be able to re-use the app although 30 days had passed.

From the docs:

> The uuid on iOS uses the identifierForVendor property. It is unique to
>   the device across the same vendor, but will be different for different
>   vendors and **will change if all apps from the vendor are deleted and
>   then reinstalled**. See the [official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor).
>
> The UUID will be the same if app is restored from a backup or iCloud
>   as it is saved in preferences. Users using older versions of this
>   plugin will still receive the same previous UUID generated by another
>   means as it will be retrieved from preferences.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to find out how many days have passed since the user opened the app the very first time, even if he deletes/reinstalls all apps made by me?

**Note:** Since I am using Phonegap/Cordova, a Cordova-compatible solution would be welcome but a native Swift/Objective-C solution would be ok too.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because the UUID property was being abused by advertisers. I don'w know what kind of app you are building, but if it's something where they'd lose their data if they delete/reinstall the app, they might choose to register.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Nah, it's a news app. My customer wants a "try before you buy" for it for 30 days. After the 30 days you'd have to sign up on their website and pay for a subscription.

Comment: Seems like a free sign up would be the best way to go, then you can register the user and give them 30 days across all devices rather than 30 days per device they install on (assuming there was an id that could be used to even pull that off since Apple removed our ability to use a single uuid without the threat of it changing on us.)

Comment: You could use an in-app purchase subscription with a free trial period. Note that if you aren't using in-app purchase then your app cannot include any link to an external website that allows the user to purchase a subscription

Comment: @Steve But with free sign ups, wouldn't the user be able to re-create a new free account every 30 days and then use the app for free again? :-(

Comment: It's not just that you can't include a link. “11.1
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected”. You have to go through Apple if you want to let the user buy functionality (not content). Also “11.9 Apps containing content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected, except for specific approved content (e.g. films, television programs, music, books)”. You cannot turn off services after 30 days, period.

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately, my customer wants to use their own subscription model they're already using on their website. So, in app purchase is not an option :-(

Comment: @robmayoff Good point, thanks!

Comment: You can write and submit the app, but you should expect Apple to reject it. Make sure your customer pays you **before** that happens.

Comment: Then you either need the user to sign up in order to get their 30 days free and track that in your server via their account or accept the risk that they may delete and re-install the app every 30 days; This is a little like dealing with movie pirates; people who go to this sort of trouble probably weren't going to be a paying customer anyway. @robmayoff is right; you can't turn off features but you can require the user to have an account before the app works; but their inability to register the account in the app will probably turn most people off

Comment: You can allow them to create a free account in the app but you will have a difficulty when it comes to convert them to a paying customer; you can't include any of that functionality or even a link to the payment website in your app

Comment: @Paulw11 Giving the user to create a free account probably won't stop them from re-creating a new free account every 30 days..

Comment: @TImo - Your customer's subscription model likely violates Apple's guidelines, and Apple may thus reject the app.  You might inform your customer before they waste their time.

Comment: Exactly, that is my point about them not becoming a paying customer. The subscription in-app purchase is a little better because the user would need to establish a new iTunes account each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app can store it's own unique ID (from a server or randomly generated perhaps) and/or a date-stamp in the iOS device's keychain.  The keychain is not cleared when an app is deleted from a device.

See Apple's [Keychain services programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

Comment: But Apple's guidelines for app approval required that an app's NOT expire basic functionality as described in the app's description.  This is a grounds for your app to be rejected or be later removed from the App store.

Comment: What if the user deletes that entry from the keychain manually or reinstalls the app?

Answer (score 0):

What about NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?

```
//    Use `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`     
    let iCloudKeyStore: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore? = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()
    let isMyAppInstalled = true
    iCloudKeyStore?.setBool(isMyAppInstalled, forKey: "isMyAppInstalled")
    iCloudKeyStore?.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

If You can Create a webService to catch and Store Device ID's on a Sqlite table, here is the Solution:

You can get Device ID like this:

```
  let DID = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
    print("Device ID is : \(DID)")
```

and then send this ID to your webSerivce like this:
on AppDelegate put this :

```
    internal static var DeviceList:[StructID] = []
```

then Create a Swift Class with name StructID, like this :

```
import Foundation


class StructID{
    internal var id:Int!
    internal var DevieID:String!
    internal var AllowInstall:String!
    internal var InstalledTime:String!
    internal var InstallCount:String!
}
```

then on Your FirstViewController You can send and store many data included how many this id installed this app or when is the first install or is this id alowed tho use this app? or anything you want !

```
 let IDs = StructID()
    IDs.DevieID = DID
    IDs.AllowInstall = AllowInstall // <declare it yourself
    IDs.InstalledTime = InstalledTime // <declare it yourself
    IDs.InstallCount = InstallCount // <declare it yourself


    var dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    dictionary["id"] = IDs.id
    dictionary["DevieID"] = IDs.DevieID
    dictionary["AllowInstall"] = IDs.AllowInstall
    dictionary["InstalledTime"] = IDs.InstalledTime
    dictionary["InstallCount"] = IDs.InstallCount



 let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.YourWebAddress.com/service.php?action=insert")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = NSTimeInterval(10)
        do {
            let jsonData =  try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            request.HTTPBody = jsonData
        } catch {
            print("json data error")
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (NSData, response, error) -> Void in
            let id = String (data: NSData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            DeviceList.id = Int(id!) // <= its id column of your table
 AppDelegate.DeviceList.append(IDs) // <= it the Device id Your are sending
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            })
        }
        task.resume()
       }
```

and your php code on your webService:

```
 function getConnection () {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "YourDatabseName_db";
        $password = "Password";
        $dbname = "YourDatabseName_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    return $conn;
}

 $action = $_GET["action"];



if ($action == "insert") {
    $conn = getConnection();
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $DeviceID = $data["DeviceID"];
    $AllowInstall = $data["AllowInstall"];
    $InstalledTime = $data["InstalledTime"];
    $InstallCount = $data["InstallCount"];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `YourDatabase_db`.`YourTableName` (`DeviceID`, `AllowInstall`, `InstalledTime `, `InstallCount `) VALUES ('$DeviceID', '$AllowInstall', '$InstalledTime', '$InstallCount')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        echo $last_id;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

finally When Your app Stars each time, you an Check all the Conditions and do what ever you want...

for readig Back from php put it on your webservice php :

```
if ($action == "selectgeneral") {
        $conn = getConnection();
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtablename";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $output = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $record = array();
                $record["id"] = $row["id"];
                $record["DevieID"] = $row["DevieID"];
                $record["AllowInstall"] = $row["AllowInstall"];
                $record["InstalledTime"] = $row["InstalledTime"];
                $record["InstallCount"] = $row["InstallCount"];
                array_push($output, $record);
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
        echo json_encode($output);
```

and if you want to read your data from your php :

```
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(NSData, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let records = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(NSData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

            for record in records {
                let record = StructID()
                record.id = Int(record["id"] as! String)
                record.DevieID = record["DevieID"] as! String
                record. AllowInstall = record["AllowInstall"] as! String
                record.InstalledTime = Int(record["InstalledTime"] as! String)
                record.InstallCount = Int(record["InstallCount"] as! String)


                AppDelegate.DeviceID.append(record)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableViewNote.reloadData()
            })
        }
        catch {
            print("Json Error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Sorry if its a little complicated.